# real time data and MS chart

Tags: c#, .net, graph, charts

I'm trying to plot a graph based on data received from serial port in real time. I get about 1000 points per second from serial port which prevents me updating in real time. currently it all goes into a list which i read from once in X milliseconds in order to update the UI. after less then a minute the graph updates start to "get out of sync"(I've tried several intervals from 50 ms to 1Sec) it "halts" then i see an update and on the same second it disappears. does anybody have a suggestion  how to solve this?

Comment: I've seen there's a fast chart that is for drawing charts in real time
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489215.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried MS Charts a while, but things were not going very well.

Now i use Highcharts. Don't know about your clientside coding skills, but with not that much jquery code and some async calls to get your data (in JSON for example), this will work very well...

Sorry, no solution, just a suggestion.